# Replace value of key using ramda.js

Tags: ramda.js

I have the following array of objects:

```
const originalArray = [
  {name: 'name1', value: 10},
  {name: 'name2', value: 20}
]
```

And the following object

```
names = {
  name1: 'generic_name_1',
  name2: 'generic_name_2'
}
```

I would like the first array to be transformed like this:

```
[
  {name: 'generic_name_1', value: 10},
  {name: 'generic_name_2', value: 20}
]
```

What I have tried so far:

```
const replaceName = (names, obj) => {
  if(obj['name'] in names){
    obj['name'] = names[obj['name']];
  }
  return obj;
}
const modifiedArray = R.map(replaceName(names), originalArray)
```

Is there a more ramda-ish way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use any Ramda functions for this.  I would simply avoid mutating the original, perhaps with code like this:

```js
const transform = (names) => (arr) => arr .map (
  ({name, ... rest}) => ({name: names [name] || name, ... rest})
)

const originalArray = [{name: 'name1', value: 10},{name: 'name2', value: 20}]
const names = {name1: 'generic_name_1',name2: 'generic_name_2'}

console .log (
  transform (names) (originalArray)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using native JS inside Ramda functions is not unramdaish. The only problem in your code is that you mutate the original object - `obj['name'] = names[obj['name']];`.

I would use R.when to check if the name exists in the `names` object, and if it does evolve the object to the new name. If it doesn't the original object would be returned.

```js
const { flip, has, prop, map, when, pipe, evolve } = R

const hasProp = flip(has)
const getProp = flip(prop)

const fn = names => map(when(
  pipe(prop('name'), hasProp(names)),
  evolve({
    name: getProp(names)
  })
))

const originalArray = [{"name":"name1","value":10},{"name":"name2","value":20},{"name":"name3","value":30}]
const names = {"name1":"generic_name_1","name2":"generic_name_2"}

const result = fn(names)(originalArray)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```